# Invalid credentials provided

Tags: git, heroku

Ao criar um app no Heroku, recebi essa mensagem

```
 C:\Users\alex.jose.silva\Documents\demo2 (master -> origin)
    λ heroku create appSpring1
    Creating ⬢ appSpring1... !
     !    Invalid credentials provided.
     !    EPERM: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\SSH\_netrc'
```

como corrigir esse erro?

Comment: Veja se isso resolve: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10777750/1377664

Comment: Como suas últimas questões são idênticas em conteúdo, apontei as outras como cópias desta daqui, que foi mais bem recebida. Não entendi o porquê de fazer 3 perguntas iguais, foi um engano?

Comment: Peço desculpas...foi um engano. Irei deletar as anteriores.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro no login do Heroku no cmd do Windows](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/287145/erro-no-login-do-heroku-no-cmd-do-windows)