# Erro no login do Heroku no cmd do Windows

Tags: git, heroku

Tento acessar os serviços do Heroku pelo cmd, porém recebo essa mensagem:

```
C:\Users\xxx.xxx.xxx
λ heroku login
 !    EPERM: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\SSH\_netrc'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das causas para este erro é a permissão de acesso do arquivo. Verifique se o arquivo está como `readonly` através das propriedades do arquivo.

Se estiver, **desmarque** a opção e tente novamente.